# Is dijkstra's algorithm fastest possible algorithm for undirected graph with no additional data?

Tags: graphs, dijkstras-algorithm

there are many similar questions, but I haven't found direct answer to this question. Consider I have **undirected**, **weighted** graph with positive weights, no additional data - hence **no heuristic** (so it is not possible to use A*), **is Dijkstra's algorithm with Fibonacci queue fastest known algorithm** in terms of big-O notation? If so, is it proved it is fastest possible algorithm? Dijkstra's with Fibonacci queue is O(|E| + |V| * log |V|)

Edit:

apparently Wikipedia answers my first part of the question:

> This is asymptotically the fastest known single-source shortest-path algorithm for arbitrary directed graphs with unbounded non-negative weights

but do we know if it is fastest **possible** algorithm?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem